# Is there such a thing as portable SQL?

Tags: sql, portability

In my experience, even though there is a SQL standard, it is quite difficult to write SQL that works, unmodified, over a large number of RDBMS.

Thus, I'd like to know if there is a subset of SQL (including DDL, schemas, etc) that is known to work on all major RDBMS, including PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQL Server and, last but not least, Oracle. What kind of pitfalls should be avoided when writing portable SQL?

By the way, is there a project whose goal is to translate a valid subset of SQL into the specific dialects used by all these vendors? I know that Hibernate and other ORM systems have to do this, but I don't want ORM, I want to write straight-to-database SQL.

Thanks!

Comment: There are **several** ANSI SQL Standards - e.g. [ANSI SQL 92](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) - portable, but usually pretty "limited" on most specific platforms.

Comment: Many ORMs make portable SQL unnecessary.

Comment: Just curious, is this a general-purpose question, or do you have a specific project or goal in mind?

Comment: Just a general-purpose question, although I'd write a translator if I had the time. This issue comes up frequently, especially when the generic product you are developing must talk to whatever databases are used by the clients. ORM is not an option.

Comment: Why is it not an option?  The core of ORM is to act as an abstraction layer between the application and the database, which is essentially what you are asking for.  Are you saying there's something about ORM solutions specifically that you can't tolerate, or you can't have an abstraction layer period?

Comment: ORM is not an option for two reasons: first, it doesn't map well with the kinds of things I'm storing in the database. The things I want to persist are not entities, just dumps of values -- possibly thousands per second (think of hundreds of sensors emitting readings, for example). Second, ORM tends to be rather slow, although I acknowledge that may be alleviated with some work on the part of the developer.

Comment: See also [Can I write portable SQL statements?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/257305/can-i-write-portable-sql-statements)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that some DBMS even ignore the most simple standards (e.g. like quoting characters or string concatenation).

So the following (100% ANSI SQL) does not run on every DBMS:

```
UPDATE some_table
    SET some_column = some_column || '_more_data';
```

And I'M not even thinking about more advanced SQL standards like recursive common table expressions (even those that support it don't always comply) or windowing functions (some only implement a very narrow subset, some do not support all options).

Regarding DDL, there is the problem with data types. `DATE` is not the same everywhere, just as `TIMESTAMP`. Not every DBMS has a `BOOLEAN` type or `TIME` type.

When it comes to constraints or domains you get even more differences.

So in a nutshell: unless you really, **really** need to be DBMS independent, don't bother with it.

Having said all that: if you do have the choice between a proprietary and standard syntax do choose the standard syntax (`OUTER JOIN` vs `(+)` or `*=`, `decode` vs `CASE`, `nvl` vs. `coalesce` and so on).

Answer (score 2):

Within each RDBMS, whatever is listed as ANSI-compliant should be the same across all of them as that is the true standard.  However, by sticking with only ANSI (i.e. portable) stuff, then you lose out on the optimized, vendor-specific functionality.  Also, just because PostgreSQL implements an ANSI function doesn't mean that it is available in any other RDBMS (but if it is available, then it should work the same).

Personally, I see no value in truly portable SQL code or a project to normalize down to a lowest-common-denominator set as each particular RDBMS is optimized differently. There is no common application language.  IF you are using C#, then you wouldn't be wanting to use stuff that can only be found in PHP or JAVA.  So just embrace the platform you are on :).

Edit: If you are writing an application that can connect to several different RDBMS's, then you will likely need to find the appropriate SQL for each particular platform, just like the authors of each of the ORM's had to do.

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but I'd still like to object to comparing the choice of different DBMS vendors to the choice between e.g. C# and Java. I think it should be more like the choice between MSVC and GCC and clang for compiling C. Many C compilers do have their own extensions, but unless you specifically need those you can stick to the standard and your code should work on any major compiler. And even if you do need compiler-specific code in some place, it is still a huge advantage if you don't need to change 98% of your code when porting.

Comment: Hi @Medo42 . I get that, but in reality the various RDBMSs are more different than similar. This isn't just about same SQL syntax producing the same result, we also need to factor in differences in datatypes and tuning. In one RDBMS it might be best to use `LEFT JOIN` but for another `NOT EXISTS` is best. Maybe not using SQL at all is best: I seem to recall that in PostgreSQL, using PL/pgSQL functions could re-use query plans but SQL couldn't. What about `"` or `'` for strings? What about Oracle allowing any encoding in `VARCHAR2`? Non-tailored SQL (except CRUD maybe) is either slow or buggy.

Answer (score 1):

Simple queries are almost always portable. Unfortunately, the list of SQL vendors that you provided vary greatly in their standards compliance. MS SQL Server is at the top of the ones that you listed in terms of complying with ANSI SQL standards, and both MySQL and Oracle are notoriously bad when it comes to standards compliance. That, of course, is not to say that they're bad RDBMS engines or that you can't write powerful queries with them, but their adherence to standards is not exactly what they're known for.

Note that you've omitted some big RDBMS players in that list, namely Sybase and IBM's DB2. Those two are generally more standards-compliant than the others, for what that's worth.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal that I can write SQL code on one product and expect it to work on another without modification is an impossible dream.

I rather think of "portability" as being a meaure of how easy it is move code to another SQL product or, crucially, to a later version of the same SQL product, noting that established SQL products tend to move *toward* the SQL Standards (e.g. SQL-92's `UPDATE` requires scalar subqueries hence is long-winded, SQL Server early on provided proprietary `JOIN..FROM` syntax then for SQL Server 2008 provided a `MERGE` syntax which supports *and* extends Standard SQL's `MERGE`).

As a rule of thumb, use Standard SQL code where your SQL product supports it (e.g. `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` rather than SQL Server's `getdate()`), otherwise prefer proprietary code that easily maps into Standard SQL code (e.g. SQL Server's `SUBSTRING()` easily maps to Standard SQL's `SUBSTRING()` using a macro). Note that some functions outside of the SQL Standard will be common to SQL products (e.g. most/all will have a `MOD()` function or operator).

Answer (score 1):

I build web applications using Alpha Five which has a feature called "Portable SQL". There are about 200 "Portability Functions". If I use a portability function, it will automatically convert to native SQL to fit whichever engine I happen to use.

So if I write "SELECT now() FROM clients", now() being a portability function, that syntax will automatically be converted to the native language depending on which I happen to use. They support 22 different SQL engines.

- DB2-SELECT CURRENT TIMESTAMP AS Expr1 FROM client
- MYSQL-SELECT Now() AS Expr1 FROM client
- MSSQL-SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS Expr1 FROM client
- SYBASE-SELECT getdate() AS Expr1 FROM client
- ODBC-SELECT {fn Now()} AS Expr1 FROM client